# is possible to bruteforce my Sha512 Authenication algorithm?

Tags: hash, sha512

I have an authentication application and don't know how secure it is.

here is the algorithm.

1) A clientToken is generated by using SHA512 hash a new guid. I have about 1000 ClientsToken generated and store in the database.

every time the caller calling my web service it need to provide the clientToken, if the clienttoken does not exists in the database, then it is not valid client.

The problem is how long does it take to brute force to get the existing ClientToken?

Comment: Hashing the guid will not improve the token. It is better to send the GUID itself as token, and to store the hash of the GUID in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GUID is a 128 bit value, with 6 bits held constant, so a total of 122 bits available. Since this is your input to the hash, you're not going to have 2^512 unique hashes in your application. This is roughly 5.3*10^36 values to check.

Say your attacker is able to calculate 1,000,000 (10^6) hashes per second (I'm not sure how reasonable that is for SHA-512, but at this size, a few orders of magnitude won't influence things that much). This works out to about 5.3*10^30 seconds to check the space (For reference, this will be far beyond the time all stars have gone dark). Also, unless you have several billion clients, a [birthday attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) probably will not remove too many orders of magnitude from this.

But, just for fun, let's say the attacker has some trick that lets him reduce the number of hashes to check by half (or some combination of reduced space to check and increased speed), either by you having that many users, or some flaw in your GUID generator, or what have you. We're still looking at well over 100 million years to find a collision.

I think you're beyond safe and into somewhat overkill territory. Also note that hashing the GUID in effect does nothing, and that GUIDs probably are not generated via a secure random number generator. You'd actually be a bit better off just generating a 128 bits (16 bytes) of randomness via whatever secure random number generator your platform uses, and using that as the shared secret.

Comment: About [80 Mega](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-lite/#performance) SHA-512 hashes per second are possible with common hardware.

Comment: Actually, does't the PC3 column there say 220Ms? I must say, that's quite something. Though, we're still looking at a post-stellar universe, or even 1 million years for my assumed halving of the space.

Comment: Yes that's right, even more impressive are the 10 Giga MD5 hashes. That's why BCrypt was invented to hash short passwords, for strong tokens SHA-512 will work well as you already pointed out.